Ошибка при инициализации playwright
npm init playwirhgt
npm error code E404
npm error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/create-playwirhgt - Not found
npm error 404
npm error 404  'create-playwirhgt@*' is not in this registry.
npm error 404
npm error 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\sherzodjon.abdumutal\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-07-29T09_42_48_259Z-debug-0.log

правильно напиши имя библиотеки каторую пытаешся скачать, 404 означает что то что ты ишеш нету в данном случее в реестре npm, вбей в поисковик имя он те правильно подскажет. либо в реестре npm глянь.

Этот вопрос похож на: Ошибка при установке playwright через пакетный менеджер npm. Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обозначив отличие и/или почему ответы на вопрос не помогли в вашем случае.
